# How to correctly display multiple parameters in URL with the same GET name for PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, url, mysqli, parameters

My parameters have different names (`tags, tags2, tags3`) but the same GET method or in other words the same column name (`tags`) in the MySQL database.

Here is the code:

```
$tags = $_GET['tags'];
$tags2 = $_GET['tags'];
$tags3 = $_GET['tags'];

$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username WHERE tags = '$tags' AND tags = '$tags2' AND tags = '$tags3' ORDER BY users.id DESC");
```

Basically I am trying to display all images with 3 different tags in the `user_images` tables.

Here is what my URL looks like, but it only displays one tag and not all 3:

https://www.example.com/app/user-tags.php?tags=aesthetic&tags2=food&tags3=dogs

The first parameter works, but not all of them. Can anyone help me where I went wrong?

I thought about doing something likes this, having `tags = aesthetic,food,dogs` in the query. But the problem is that I think the result would read that as, "Find all images with the tags of aestheticfooddogs" instead of tags with aesthetic, food, and dogs.

Comment: Change `$tags2 = $_GET['tags'];` to `$tags2 = $_GET['tags2'];` and do the same for tags3.

Comment: @Dave Ok I did it, same to `$tags3`, but this time nothing displays. I thought the `$_GET` holds the name of the column from the SQL Database, that's why I kept it the same.

Comment: `$_GET` is the array of parameters from the URL. The sample URL you used has 3 names and values, tags, tags2 and tags3. tags contains aesthetic, tags2 contains food and tags3 contains dogs. If you `var_dump($_GET);` before the code you posted what do you get?

Comment: Here are the results before the code, `array(3) { ["tags"]=> string(9) "aesthetic" ["tags2"]=> string(4) "food" ["tags3"]=> string(4) "dogs" } `. I also did it to the $_GET changes and got the same results.

Comment: My first comment stands and is corrected especially after you just verified what I said. `$tags2 = $_GET['tags2'];` will result in `$tags2` containing `food`. You confusion is in your SQL query. How is your `tags` column in SQL defined?

Comment: Do I have to change the query or the url parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, in the SQL I have the name as `tags` with `text` and '`utf8_general_ci` `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to look in the `tags` column in your table and find any matches for the values passed in the URL. If you want to find ANY of the tag values change the use of `AND` to `OR` instead.

```
$tags  = $_GET['tags'];
$tags2 = $_GET['tags2'];
$tags3 = $_GET['tags3'];

$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users
JOIN user_images ON users.username = user_images.username
WHERE tags LIKE '%" . $tags  . "%' OR
      tags LIKE '%" . $tags2 . "%' OR
      tags LIKE '%" . $tags3 . "%'
ORDER BY users.id DESC")
```